# CentOS Docker Container running Libero SoC: Unable to to connect to X Server

Tags: docker

I am running Libero SoC on a CentOS Docker Container (CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)). This container will be used to build FPGA code within a CI/CD pipeline. When I attempt to execute a script (that simply prints `"Hello, world"`) with the command
`libero SCRIPT:printhelloworld.tcl`

I receive the following error:

```
libero_bin: cannot connect to X server
```

I would not have expected libero to require an X server just to run a .tcl script.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you running the container (syntax)? Could just need something like `-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix` ...also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613474/using-x11-forwarding-for-docker-containers

Answer (score 2):

Suggest looking at this example of libero docker image that uses Ubuntu: https://github.com/AngelTerrones/ubuntu-libero